# Code work properly while pressing F8 and doesn't while pressing F5

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code, which create sheets with some formats. I have a problem that formatting doesn't work properly (for example it changes color of different range or it doesn't merge cells).

I thought that maybe I did something in wrong order or something like that so I started to press F8 from the beggining to very end. And while doing it, it made exactly a sheet like I wanted.

My code is quite long coz there is many subs inside so I'll try to write how it works and insert important parts. If it won't be enought, I'll put here the rest of my code.

- It takes name of the first project from ResourcesProjects sheet. It is stored in sResourcesProjectName variable (it works properly)
- Next, it calls 3 subs which create 3 sheets: ResourceSheet, DesignExecutionSheet and RisksSheet.
  All of this subs have code to create and format created sheet.
  First sub (ResourceSheet) works properly, formatting is exactly like I wanted.
  The problem is with subs DesignExecutionSheet and RisksSheet. It is not formatted well when it goes by F5.

  ```
  Private Sub DesignExecutionSheet()

  Application.PrintCommunication = True
  ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  On Error Resume Next

  bSheetFound = False

  For Each wsSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      wsSheet.Activate
      sDesignSheetName = sResourcesProjectName & "_Design_Execution"

      If wsSheet.Name = sDesignSheetName Then ' --- if that sheet already exists, then exit sub and go to next project
          bSheetFound = True
          Exit Sub
      End If

  Next wsSheet

      Sheets.Add.Name = sResourcesProjectName & "_Design_Execution"
      Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Activate

  Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

  Captions sResourcesProjectName & " Design & Execution", RGB(235, 241, 222)

  Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 3
  Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 25
  Rows("8:8").RowHeight = 25
  Rows("12:12").RowHeight = 25
  Rows("17:17").RowHeight = 25

  Range("C8:E8,C12:E12,C17:E17").Select

  With Selection
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
      .WrapText = False
      .Orientation = 0
      .AddIndent = False
      .IndentLevel = 0
      .ShrinkToFit = False
      .ReadingOrder = xlContext
      .MergeCells = True
  End With
  Selection.Font.Bold = True
  With Selection.Font
      .Name = "Calibri"
      .Size = 12
      .Strikethrough = False
      .Superscript = False
      .Subscript = False
      .OutlineFont = False
      .Shadow = False
      .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
      .Color = RGB(118, 147, 60)
  End With

  Range("C8:E8").FormulaR1C1 = "STATUS OF REQUIREMENTS"
  Range("C12:E12").FormulaR1C1 = "TEST EXECUTION"
  Range("C17:E17").FormulaR1C1 = "VIR/SCR"

      Range("9:9,10:10,13:13,14:14,15:15,18:18,19:19,20:20").Select
  Selection.RowHeight = 20
  Range("C9:C10,C13:C15,C18:C20").Select
  With Selection.Interior
      .Pattern = xlSolid
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
  End With
  Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Select
  Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
  Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
  With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .ThemeColor = 1
      .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
      .Weight = xlThin
  End With
  With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .ThemeColor = 1
      .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
      .Weight = xlThin
  End With
  With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .ThemeColor = 1
      .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
      .Weight = xlThin
  End With
  With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
      .LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .ThemeColor = 1
      .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
      .Weight = xlThin
  End With
  Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
  Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
  Range("A6").Select


  Range("D9:D10,D13:D15,D18:D20").Select
  With Selection
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
      .WrapText = False
      .Orientation = 0
      .AddIndent = False
      .IndentLevel = 0
      .ShrinkToFit = False
      .ReadingOrder = xlContext
      .MergeCells = False
      .Font.Color = RGB(89, 89, 89)
  End With
  Selection.Font.Bold = True

  Range("D9").Value = "ASSIGNED TO IT&V:"
  Range("D10").Value = "COVERED BY IT&V:"
  Range("D13").Value = "EXECUTED:"
  Range("D14").Value = "PASSED:"
  Range("D15").Value = "FAILED:"
  Range("D18").Value = "OPEN:"
  Range("D19").Value = "CLOSED:"
  Range("D20").Value = "VERIFIED:"

  Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Visible = xlSheetHidden


  'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

  End Sub
  ```

with RisksSheet() there is similar problem so I don't put here code from that sub.

- After calling this subs, there is only this in code:

  ```
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

  End Sub
  ```

EDIT:

I edited my code like Luboš Suk suggested. Now the problem is different. By pressing F8 it works again properly, but by pressing F5 there is an error "application defined or object defined error" in line

```
    With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C8:E8,C12:E12,C17:E17")
```

What is more, the error isn't appear when I set a breakpoint in main sub in line

```
   Call DesignExecutionSheet
```

and press F5 twice.

I also figured out that when I don't multiple ranges (for example only "C8:E8" instead of "C8:E8,C12:E12,C17:E17") it also works.
But I have many ranges inside, the code will be very long if I'll divide all of that ranges.

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub DesignExecutionSheet()

    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'On Error Resume Next

        bSheetFound = False

        For Each wsSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            'wsSheet.Activate
            sDesignSheetName = sResourcesProjectName & "_Design_Execution"

            If wsSheet.Name = sDesignSheetName Then ' --- if that sheet already exists, then exit sub and go to next project
                bSheetFound = True
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next wsSheet

            Sheets.Add.Name = sResourcesProjectName & "_Design_Execution"
            'Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Activate

        With Sheets(sDesignSheetName)

            .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

            Captions sResourcesProjectName & " Design & Execution", RGB(235, 241, 222)

            .Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 3
            .Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 25
            .Rows("8:8").RowHeight = 25
            .Rows("12:12").RowHeight = 25
            .Rows("17:17").RowHeight = 25
        End With


            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C8:E8,C12:E12,C17:E17")
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = True
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With

            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C8:E8,C12:E12,C17:E17").Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Size = 12
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .Color = RGB(118, 147, 60)
            End With

            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C8:E8").FormulaR1C1 = "STATUS OF REQUIREMENTS"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C12:E12").FormulaR1C1 = "TEST EXECUTION"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C17:E17").FormulaR1C1 = "VIR/SCR"


            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("9:9,10:10,13:13,14:14,15:15,18:18,19:19,20:20").RowHeight = 20
            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:C10,C13:C15,C18:C20").Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
            End With
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ThemeColor = 1
                .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ThemeColor = 1
                .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ThemeColor = 1
                .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ThemeColor = 1
                .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("C9:E10,C13:E15,C18:E20").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
           ' .Range("A6").Select


            With Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D9:D10,D13:D15,D18:D20")
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
                .Font.Color = RGB(89, 89, 89)
            End With
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D9:D10,D13:D15,D18:D20").Font.Bold = True

            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D9").Value = "ASSIGNED TO IT&V:"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D10").Value = "COVERED BY IT&V:"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D13").Value = "EXECUTED:"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D14").Value = "PASSED:"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D15").Value = "FAILED:"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D18").Value = "OPEN:"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D19").Value = "CLOSED:"
            Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Range("D20").Value = "VERIFIED:"


    Sheets(sDesignSheetName).Visible = xlSheetHidden


    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Probably a race condition. E.g. your code tries to do something while Excel is still busy with a previous request.

Comment: That `On Error Resume Next` is really not helping you. There are a lot of simple errors there - eg trying to create a sheet that already exists, and not specifying the correct sheet name.

Comment: Ok, when I edited my code, the error appear. Thanks for suggest.

Comment: But now I have problems with ranges. I described it in my question. Maybe someone would know what is the problem?

Comment: I think you can shorten code by setting border properties to all borders at once. Not one by one

Comment: Yes, I did that already, but this code is still really long, when I can't multiple ranges :/

Answer (score 1):

So your main problem will be here, where you activate worksheet and then working with it.

```
    For Each wsSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsSheet.Activate
    sDesignSheetName = sResourcesProjectName & "_Design_Execution"

    If wsSheet.Name = sDesignSheetName Then ' --- if that sheet already exists, then exit sub and go to next project
        bSheetFound = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next wsSheet
```

I suggest you to use better aproach in your code. Properly declare variables, and work with sheets and cells like relative objects and **AVOID .activate and .select**

In short therm use something like this. This approach is much more robust for you and readable.

```
Sub doSomething()

    Dim myCuteSheet As Worksheet
    Set myCuteSheet = Sheets("pinkRidignSheet")

    With myCuteSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(5,5)) 'then do something with range
        .Cells(15,20) 'do something with cell
        .Columns ("F") 'do something with column

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I edited my code like you suggest (now there is not any .activate and .select) but another problem occured. I edited my first post with question and described it.